# How to get a SPFieldLookupValue from an SPListItem?

Tags: lookup-column, splistitem, spfielduser

When you get an `SPListItemCollection` from a `SPList.GetItems(SPQuery)` request, and the items have `SPFieldUser` or `SPFieldLookup` fields, what is the sexy way to get typed values, not the `item["Field"].ToString().Split('#')[1]` way, please?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
new SPFieldLookupValue(item["FieldName"] as String).LookupValue
```

you probably want to check if `item["FieldName"]` is not null or empty before doing this.

`SPFieldUserValue` works similarly, but you need to pass in an `SPWeb` into the constructor, which you can retrieve from your `SPListItem` using `SPListItem.ParentList.ParentWeb`

Comment: or .ToString() and yes check for null always

Comment: Cool, at least this way we are protected from cases when hash/pound-sign(#) appears in the value. Thanks.

Comment: cool - just googled for this question and stumbled upon my own answer :)

Comment: I wrote an article about the whole get/set Lookup/User field method, which may be useful: http://tsstsst.com/easily-accessing-lookup-and-user-fields/

Comment: for CSOM, use FieldLookupValue from Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.